# Angular getting the response of a service responding undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having issues getting the data returned from my service.

I'm using `Angular 8`.

Here is the code:

In the service

```
callit(url: string) {
    this.subscription = this.socket$.subscribe(
      (message) => {
        return message;
      },
      (err) => {
        return err;
      },
      () => console.warn('Completed!')
    );
}
```

In the component.

I've tried:

```
getResultFromService() {
    var res = this.myservice.callit(myurl);
}
```

The above res says undefined.

I've tried:

```
getResultFromService() {
    this.myservice.connect(myurl).subscribe
}
```

But subscribe is giving me this error:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)

How can I get the result from the service return without using a `promise`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Don't think this is a direct duplicate, it seems more a question about observables. Re-phrasing the question towards that direction with regards to what your trying to achieve may be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

.service

```
callit(url: string) {
    return this.socket$
}
```

.component

```
getResultFromService() {
    this.myservice.callit(myurl).subscribe(
      (message) => {
        res = message;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log('error')
      },
      () => console.warn('Completed!')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `callIt` function returns nothing.

So from the outside you cannot call `.subscribe` as your trying to call it on undefined.

Now within your `callIt` method your are subscribing to the observable.

If you wish to keep that logic you will be instead returning a subscription which has no `.subscribe` method. You could move the subscribe logic outside the `callIt` method and return the observable.

Or you could still return an observable but use `pipes` to intercept the messages, and still subscribe from the outside. This would allow you to still perform any logic you have within your `service.callIt` and still subscribe on the outside.

```js
    return this.socket$
        .pipe(tap((message) => console.log(message))
        .pipe(catchError((e) => console.error(e)))
        .pipe(finally(() => console.log('Completed')))
```